# API Params - {person: {name: 'John'}} vs {name: 'John'}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest

When creating a restful API is it better to have clients send over the object name or just the attributes.  For example the body for **POST /people/**:

**Option 1:**
{person: name: 'John'}

**Option 2:**
{name: 'John'}

I generally see **Option 2** in most APIs, but I'm running into a sticky point.  I'm using Rails, so if I ever want to have an action that handles both html and json requests, don't I need to use **Option 1** (since Rails forms send params prefaced with the object type)?

Are there any pros / cons for one option vs the other?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time sending `{person: {name: 'John'}}` is unnecessary, as when you are POST'ing or GET'ing, you will generally know based on the URL the type of response to expect or send ('person' in this case).

There are use-cases for Option 1, however. Using Option 2, you are relying on the URL that you are GET'ing/POST'ing to give you typing information - it is not explicitly declared in the JSON. This can be good, as if you GET from `/service/person/{id}`, the 'person' tag on `{person: {name: 'John'}}` is redundant. However, if you have a more RPC-like service such as a service you POST to to validate your payload: `/service/validate` or something similar, you might need that extra information so the service can determine the type.